# How to refelct changes after updation?

Tags: jsp

I have one JSP page on which i am providing database result in tabular format with option for Edit/Update through href.After clicking on that link one pop up window will open & you can edit the containts after submitting the changes i want to reflect that changes to previous page & all this has to be done using JSP

Comment: Please provide the code what have you tried. Update the data to database and in your JSP page, always query the data and display the result. So that JSP page will be showing updated data always

Answer (score 0):

Reload the page after submission via Javascript `location.reload();`